# Find the degree of splitting field of a separable polynomial over finite field

Tags: extension-field, splitting-field, separable-extension

Question:

> Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ over finite field $F=\mathbb{F}_q$
>   and $E$ be the splitting field of $f$. If $f$ has $n$ simple roots
>   over $E$, can we say that $[E:F] \mid n$ ? If it's true, show it.

Example:$F=\mathbb{F}_3$, $f(x)=x^4+1$, $E=F(\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(\alpha)=0$. Then $[E:F]=2$ and $\deg(f)=4$. It has $[E:F]\mid \deg(f)$.

Example:$g=\mathbb{F}_5$, $f(x)=x(x-1)$, $E=F(\beta)$, where $\beta\in \mathbb{C}$ and $g(\beta)=0$. Then $[E:F]=1$ and $\deg(g)=2$. It also has $[E:F]\mid \deg(g)$.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: 1 2 are true, but 3 and "$[E:F]=n$" is false

Comment: Consider $f(x) = x^4+1$ over $\Bbb F_3$

Comment: @KennyLau is "$[E:F] \mid n$" true ?

Comment: Even simpler: consider $\;f(x)=x(x-1)\;$ over any field...

Comment: @DonAntonio He asked "if $f$ is irreducible" in his now deleted comment

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks for your comments. I edit the question in order to include the two examples and give my observation.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your counter example. I edit the question and give my new observation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f=gh$, where $g$ is irreducible of degree $2$ and $h$ is irreducible of degree $3$. If $a$ is a root of $g$, then the splitting field of $f$ is the same as the splitting field of $h$ over $F(a)$ (which is the splitting field of $g$).

Can you show that $[E:F(a)]=3$, that is, $h$ is irreducible over $F(a)$?

Comment: If $h$ is irreducible over $F(a)$, then $[E:F]=[E:F(a)]*[F(a):F]=2*3=6$, but $\deg(f)=2+3=5$, So $[E:F] \nmid deg(f)$. Am I right?

Comment: In this case, does $f$ have $5$ distinct simple roots over $E$ ?

Comment: @zongxiangyi Yes, of course.

Comment: why $f$ has 5 distinct simple roots over $E$ ? Any hints?

Comment: @zongxiangyi A finite field is perfect. So irreducible polynomials have distinct roots in their splitting field.

Comment: $g$ has 2 distinct roots and $h$ has 3 distinct roots, so $f$ has 5 distinct roots. Is any one polynomial $f$ over $F$ has exactly $\deg(f)$ distinct roots over its splitting field?  Since polynomial ring is Unique factorization domain.

Comment: @zongxiangyi $(x-1)^2$ doesn't have two distinct roots in its splitting field. But here $g$ and $h$ have different roots.

Comment: I see, it requires that $f$ should be square-free over $F$. Conversely, if $f$ has $\deg(f)$ distinct roots over its splitting field, does it imply that $f$ is square-free over $F$ ?

Comment: @zongxiangyi My hint points to a counterexample. The statement that $[E:F]\mid n$ is not true in general.

Comment: Thanks. Your counterexample does meets the condition in my question. It seens that my observation only holds for $n=2$.